# Flutter - How to access model object across screens with GetX?

Tags: flutter, dart, parameter-passing, flutter-getx

I have 3 screens A, B, C

When I shift from A--> B, I pass the model object as an argument, and then I access it on screen B.
Now, when I press Back button on Screen C, I come back to screen B. Now the model object is empty since I am not passing any data from screen C.

How do I access the model on screen B when coming back from screen C.
Can I maintain a common model object using GetX. If yes, how?

Those who are going to ask what I have tried, I am passing and receiving the model as an argument, from A to B. And I haven't tried maintaining the model state using GetX since I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

If the first controller is not disposed you can access the controller from anywhere using `Get.find()`

```
Controller controller = Get.find(Controller);
```

and to access the data just the same way like when initializing it:

`contrller.objName`

If you are using the same controller most of the times just make a static instance of it inside the controller:

```
class Controller extends GetxController {
  static Controller to = Get.find();
}
```

then access the static instance:

```
final Controller Controller = Controller.to;
```

Comment: Thank you but I know how to access the controller. What I don't know is whether the model object (data object) should and can be stored in the controller, and should it be accessed that way? I couldn't find any example where the model is stored in the controller.

Comment: It's the logic of your application, in some cases there is objects should be accessed all the time like if you are making authentication controller every time you open the app you should authenticate and the user data can be accessed in each page of the program, but if you making somewhat of friends list and trying to have an object for certain pages you can just try to store the data somewhere and pass only the key and search for the data whenever you need